# Two finger touchscreen gestures on ubuntu 13?

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen

Ubuntu worked with my new touchscreen enabled notebook (Dell Inspiron 14R) out-of-the-box, which was a pleasant surprise. But it seems to have only three and four finger gestures, as hinted here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

But the most common patterns like pinch to zoom, or two-finger scrolling are absent (maybe a legal issue? are those patented?). I have the two-finger scrolling gesture correctly working in my trackpad.

I saw some videos of people using `ginn` to add this kind of gestures. I installed `ginn` from the repositories with `apt-get`, but when I try to run it I get a `error subscribing to gestures`.

Did anyone around managed to make something like this work? Any pointers on why `ginn` is not loading?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a ginn or touchegg problem. Unity handles multitouch guestures but does not support scrolling and long touch. x11 evdev driver also does not support 3rd mouse button click emulation and scrolling on touchscreens. And there is no software to do something with it. There is only one way - remove guesture support from unity sources, recompile, disable unity updates and install ginn/touchegg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo killall ginn
```

and then run ginn again.